# Direct firmware load for ath10k failed with Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, laptop, pci, acer

I'm using Arch Linux (4.8.13-1) on an Acer Spin 5 notebook. WIFI is working, but there are some errors in `dmesg | grep ath` which I don't understand:

```
[    2.269128] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    2.546004] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    2.546040] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    2.556185] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 target 0x05020001 chip_id 0x003821ff sub 105b:e0a1
[    2.556192] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 0 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    2.557620] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 79cea2c7
[    2.625627] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 93da0176
[    4.406204] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    4.412611] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x69
[    4.412613] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    4.412614] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    4.412615] ath: Regpair used: 0x69
```

`lspci -v` shows this information about the network controller

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device e0a1
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 280
    Memory at b1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

I would like to know how to fix this. I think this might solve some issues I'm having with the controller. I somehow cannot correctly connect to my Universitys WIFI. I thought this might have to do mith these errors which appear in `dmesg`. I tried NetworkManager, connman, wicd, netctl, and with all of them I could only get an IP-address in the network but no connection to the internet. Same with the Universitys eduroam network. I already tried lots of different configurations, but none worked.

This is the output of `iwconfig`

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"MY-WIFI"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 3C:7A:8A:F7:A2:C8   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:16   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

And `iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|cipher'` gives me this

```
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

                    ESSID:"MY-WIFI"
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    ESSID:""
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    ESSID:"20da86"
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    ESSID:"0856e0"
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    ESSID:""
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    ESSID:"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    ESSID:"20da86"
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
```

Comment: What is the issue?  Please edit the question to include what is wrong and results for `iwconfig; iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|cipher'`

Comment: I just edited it.

Comment: I would try turning off power management with `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` and see if you can connect.  Networks using TKIP are probably going to be problematic.  I don't see any issue with the firmware as these devices only need a couple files, a firmware-4.bin or 5, board.bin and some have a board-2.bin

Comment: Okay, thank you, I'll try that. But do you have any idea what causes the error messages in `dmesg`?

Comment: The direct firmware load errors are normal for most users as they won't be using the wifi card as an access point.  You could check `cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` to see what it has for a nameserver listed as mine has always been 127.0.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I little bit late for a party but I also had to connect to `eduroam` at some point of time and here is my config that works (for me at least):

```bsh
Description='Eduroam Tartu Student Village'
Interface=wlp8s0
Connection=wireless
Security=wpa-configsection
IP=dhcp
WPAConfigSection=(
        'ssid="eduroam"'
        'proto=RSN WPA'
        'key_mgmt=WPA-EAP'
        'eap=PEAP'
        'identity="<mylogin>"'
        'password="<mypass>"'
        'phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2 password=<mypassagain>"'
)
```

And also I receive the same errors as you. Though it causes my wireless card to behave weirdly sometimes. After the last update it even fails to reconnect after waking up from a sleep.